# How to reshape this array with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

My file looks like this

```
3.766204987418e+00  3.016098278453e+00  2.882128625608e+00  2.789447648712e+00  2.704276250639e+00 
 2.540138572067e+00  2.318587560199e+00  2.272640952350e+00  2.138794921589e+00
```

I have also code to read it

```
import numpy as np

zxyr=[]

with open('det.txt') as f:
    zxyr=list(f)

c=np.asarray(zxyr)
print c.shape
print len(c)
```

which produces

```
(2,)
2
```

How to reshape array to have (9,) shape?

EDIT
I have tried

```
import numpy as np      

c = np.loadtxt('det.txt')
print (c.shape)
```

BUt

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kiev.py", line 3, in <module>
    c = np.loadtxt('det.txt')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 856, in loadtxt
    X = np.array(X, dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: the good way is `c=np.loadtxt('test.txt')` . 2 it is because youhave two line in your file. remove the Line return.

Comment: You have to read in the file as numbers.  Print out zxyr, and you'll see the problem.  You fed numpy the wrong information for building the array you want.  Reshaping won't help at this point.

Comment: I think that error is because the 2 rows in your text file have different numbers of columns.  Try using `numpy.genfromtxt` using information from the documentation found here http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @B.M. said in the comments you need to use `np.loadtxt`. As shown below:

```
import numpy as np      

c = np.loadtxt('mytextfile.txt)
print (c.shape)
```

This gets the data from the file and puts it into a numpy array.
If the text file in my example is the same as yours then it will have the shape `(9,)` as you require.

Another method you can do is the following:

```
with open('mytextfile.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

Comment: @sinisha I have updated my answer. See if that helps.